# Rails how to pass parse data from sql view to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, database-view

I followed the excellent [post](https://rietta.com/blog/2015/03/30/adding-rake-db-views-for-sql-views-to-a-rails-project/) from [Frank Rietta](https://rietta.com/about/#frank-rietta) about "Adding a Rake Task for SQL Views to a Rails Project". I like his point of view about database views in rails and his dry approach.

I am able to do `rake db:views` and my view is created but I am not able to get the information in the model, this is my `models/reports/revenue.rb`

```
class Report::Revenue < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'report_revenues'
end
```

I changed the extension because I am using Rails 5.0.0

If I execute the `rails console --sandbox` and there I execute `Report::Revenue` I get the following

```
2.3.1 :004 > Report::Revenue
NameError: uninitialized constant Report
```

I am not sure what I am missing

Comment: Did you add the reports folder to autoload_paths? If not, try adding `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/reports)` to `config/application.rb`

Comment: Thank you @user3033467 I tried that but it did not work, but it helped me to realize that the problem was that I was misspelling  Report in the revenue.rb file, I should write Reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails expects module names and folder names to match. Note that you mixed singular and plural.

That said: you have to change your model to:

```
class Reports::Revenue < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'report_revenues'
end
```

*Or* move your model into a folder named `models/report/revenue.rb`.